# I missed the four rakath sunnath salat before dhuhr, should I perform that later according to Hanafi madhab?

Tags: salat, sunnah, hanafi

I entered the mosque during the time of iqamath of Dhuhr salat, so I joined the congregation and prayed the fard salat and then prayed two rakath of sunnah salat. So should I perform the four rakath of sunnah salat later?

According to Hanafi madhab, is it better to make up the four rakaths of sunnah salat later?

Comment: "should" is a wrong expression, but you could do that of course, however there might be differences between madhabs on the issue of qada' of non-oblugatory prayers.

Comment: according to Hanafi madhab, is it better to make up the four rakaths of sunnah salat later? @Medi1Saif

Comment: So far I've never investigated for hanafi madhab, i know that shafi'i and hanbali seem to allow it on the whole. Maliki for fajr, shaf' and witr AFAIK.